# Free SMS Gateway Engine

Tags: sms, kannel

Recently I was looking for SMS (mainly) gateway, free, and preferably, open source. I ran into [Kannel](http://www.kannel.org) which fits my needs so far, and more. However, I was hoping for something that is Windows-based (Kannel is Linux-based)... well, I know Kannel can be compiled and run using Cygwin, but it won't be as reliable as on Linux.

Does anyone know about similar thing on Windows? I'm not looking for a full-featured enterprise solution, something as simple as Kannel (and engine with few API's) is okay with me.

Comment: Why would Cygwin be less reliable?

Answer (score 3):

http://smsrobot.sourceforge.net

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Looks interesting from the first look. I'll give it a try whenever I get a chance, and update here.

Answer (score 2):

Cygwin is not necessarily less reliable.  If Kannel works on that, my advice would just be to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I know one working Kannel installer build (1.4.3 and CVS) for Windows prepared by archi.tech company. It's built using cygwin and includes some patches for better stability.

This is available here: http://www.thearchitech.com/downloads/

Comment: It's another implementation for Cygwin... I'll pass, but it can be useful for somebody else :)